# Why button click trigger is different from setTimeout() trigger?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs5

Consider the following, almost identical, two snippets.

The difference is:

- the first one uses `setTimeout()` to trigger the event
- the second one triggers the event when the button is clicked

If you check the console, you'll see that the last two lines in Snippet 1  are:

```
App rendering 1 folder(s)
Observed js
```

and in Snippet 2 are:

```
Observed js
App rendering 1 folder(s)
```

**Question:** Why is the order reversed?

[setTimeout() playground](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/dvOdPz?editors=0010)

[Button playground](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/jBVZOo?editors=0010)

---

### Snippet 1: setTimeout() trigger

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.events$ = new Rx.Subject();
    this.eventsByName$ = this.events$.groupBy(e => e.name);
    
    this.state = {};
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Emitting event');
      
      this.events$.next({
        type: 'ADD_FOLDER',
        name: 'js',
        permissions: 400
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.eventsByName$.subscribe(folderEvents$ => {
      const folder = folderEvents$.key;
      
      console.log(`New stream for "${folder}" created`);

      folderEvents$.subscribe(e => {
        console.log(`Observed ${e.name}`);
      });
      
      this.setState({
        [folder]: folderEvents$
      });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const folders = Object.keys(this.state);
    
    console.log(`App rendering ${folders.length} folder(s)`);
    
    return (
      <div>
        {
          folders.map(folder => (
            <div key={folder}>
              {folder}
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.2.0/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

### Snippet 2: Button trigger

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.events$ = new Rx.Subject();
    this.eventsByName$ = this.events$.groupBy(e => e.name);
    
    this.state = {};
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.eventsByName$.subscribe(folderEvents$ => {
      const folder = folderEvents$.key;
      
      console.log(`New stream for "${folder}" created`);
      
      folderEvents$.subscribe(e => {
        console.log(`Observed ${e.name}`);
      });
      
      this.setState({
        [folder]: folderEvents$
      });
    });
  }
  
  onClick = () => {
    console.log('Emitting event');
    
    this.events$.next({
      type: 'ADD_FOLDER',
      name: 'js',
      permissions: 400
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    const folders = Object.keys(this.state);
    
    console.log(`App rendering ${folders.length} folder(s)`);
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>
          Add event
        </button>
        <div>
          {
            folders.map(folder => (
              <div key={folder}>
                {folder}
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.2.0/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are run in a different order because React tries to batch `setState()` calls together, so calling `setState()` does not cause the component to re-render synchronously, but instead waits until the event callback returns.

However, it only does this if and only if your call to `setState` was the result of a React-driven event, like `onClick` is. When you're using `setTimeout`, React (currently) has no way to know when you're done, so it cannot batch them together. Instead, it synchronously re-renders right then.

Best I can tell, React docs only mention this behavior indirectly in passing:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of **calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.**
>
> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

If you want React to batch things, you would need to wrap your callback code inside `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates`, which as the name suggests is not a stable API so it can (and likely will) change without warning.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
    console.log('Emitting event');

    this.events$.next({
      type: 'ADD_FOLDER',
      name: 'js',
      permissions: 400
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

Ideally, your code would be structured in a way in which the order does not matter.